# How to delete the element of an object if the element is array?

Tags: javascript, lodash

want to remove some fields from a complex object.

```
var obj1={title:"T1",name="name1",classes:[
{id:1,scheme:1,cName:"Cls1"},
{id:2,scheme:2,cName:"Cls2"},
{id:3,scheme:3,cName:"Cls3"},]}
```

I want to remove 'scheme' & 'cName' from classes for every class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on `obj.classes` and destrcuture the properties to be removed and return the other properties.

**Note**: The below method will modify original object.

```js
var obj1={title:"T1",name:"name1",classes:[ {id:1,scheme:1,cName:"Cls1"}, {id:2,scheme:2,cName:"Cls2"}, {id:3,scheme:3,cName:"Cls3"}]}

obj1.classes = obj1.classes.map(({cName,scheme,...rest}) => rest);
console.log(obj1);
```

If there are only three properties `scheme`, `id` and `cName` and you want to remove two of them. Then its better to return the remain property from `map()`

```js
var obj1={title:"T1",name:"name1",classes:[ {id:1,scheme:1,cName:"Cls1"}, {id:2,scheme:2,cName:"Cls2"}, {id:3,scheme:3,cName:"Cls3"}]}

obj1.classes = obj1.classes.map(({id}) => ({id}));
console.log(obj1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `map()` with your `classes` property.
`map()` will return new array according to the property you want to get.

If you want to an `id` collection, just do the following code:

```js
var obj1={
  title:"T1",
  name: "name1",
  classes: [
    {id: 1, scheme: 1, cName: "Cls1"},
    {id:2, scheme: 2, cName: "Cls2"},
    {id:3, scheme: 3, cName: "Cls3"}
   ]
}

obj1.classes = obj1.classes.map((item) => item.id);

console.log(obj1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like,

```js
let obj1={title:"T1",
          name:"name1",
          classes:[{id:1,scheme:1,cName:"Cls1"},
                   {id:2,scheme:2,cName:"Cls2"},
                   {id:3,scheme:3,cName:"Cls3"}]};

obj1.classes.forEach((el) => { delete el.scheme;
                                delete el.cName;});
                                
console.log(obj1);
```